# CanCan Abilities Definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

In my rails application, my user is able to login once and switch between accounts as they please. When they do, I need to reinitialize their abilities since the permissions are set at the account level in the database.

My initial thought is to initialize the ability class when I detect a change in the account but not sure how to accomplish this.

I am of course open to any other idea. I am new to CanCan.

Comment: The `Ability` instance, like almost every other object in your rails app, is created and destroyed for every request. You don't need to reinitialize it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The Ability class is where all user permissions are defined.

Example:

```
class Ability

  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

The 'can' method is used to define permissions and requires two arguments. The first one is the action you're setting the permission for, the second one is the class of object you're setting it on.